# startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL local file path?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, icloud

Where does `startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:error` method save downloaded file in local?
Is it the same as given `URL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , its the same URL

The file in place before it downloads from iCloud to the device is a placeholder of sorts.

You can check the status of the URL with the key `NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey`

```
NSURL *foo = file://cloud/container/reference/tofile;

NSNumber *isDownloadedValue = NULL;

BOOL success = [foo getResourceValue:&isDownloadedValue forKey: NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadedKey error:NULL];

if (success && ![isDownloadedValue boolValue]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:foo error:NULL];
}
```

Theres no error handling in that snippet which you will want to do in production code.